# FPDF error displaying image

Tags: php, image, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to generate PDF. I have some pictures on my server and I'm trying to display them in a PDF. I don't get any error message and my php page just shows an HTTP ERROR 500. The link to the image is correct, I can access it in my browser but when I put it in the `Image()`, it just doesn't work.

```html
<?php
require ('../include/fpdf181/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {

}

$pdf->Image($link, 130, 240, 70, 50);

$pdf->Output();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have poorly declared parameters.

$ pdf-> Image ('path_of_the_image', 130, 240, 70, 50, $ link,);

But the solution is to enable zlib, if you manage a hosting or do it locally in xampp it is enabled by default:

-First Optimize Website leave it in Compress All Content.
-You have to go to select php version there you have to enable zlib.output_compression.

Comment: You can use markup for making your answers better and cleaner ;)